# Questions about app I just submitted to the App Store

Tags: xcode, ios7, in-app-purchase, iad

First off, can apps have an underscore in the name? The name I chose was taken, but I realized that because of the logo and style of the game it would work with an underscore at the end, so that's the name I used in iTunes connect. Will Apple reject it for this? I haven't seen any apps with an underscore in them.

Second, I'm testing the release version of my app (compiled using the release settings), and my in app purchase no longer works. It says invalid username/password, but it doesn't say sandbox mode. Is this normal? Will it work whenever the app is released?  Also, will the iAds load real ads and will Game Center not be in sandbox mode? I'm pretty sure Game Center wasn't in sandbox the first time I started the release, but now it is.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is there a specific way you have to search for it? When I search for _ or "_" only two apps show up, and neither have an underscore.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. I was looking at the suggested searches when you enter _. You're right though. When I hit search it only has two apps. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relax... Take a deep breath and calm down. The IAP is most likely not yet approved, iAds will show just fine, and GameCenter login depends more on if you use a test account or not, and it will be fine most likely.

First app?

:)

Comment: Yep! Thanks, I figured that was the case. The only thing I'm still kind of concerned about is the underscore. I haven't been able to find an app in the App Store with one, even though it was allowed in iTunes connect.

Comment: Only Apple will be able to give you an answer on that one definitely.